# Word for "function performed on top of job description"

Tags: single-word-requests

In a resume, I want to tag various things done as "extraneous to what the job description specified".  These things were achieved on top of regular tasks, so the candidate went above and beyond what was expected and contributed those too.

The goal is both to justify/explain the presence of those accomplishments despite them being outside the stated professional role and to prop up the candidate for surpassing expectations.

"Extracurricular" came to mind, but has a strong 'school' connotation that I'd like to avoid.

I was tempted to invent something like "Ex-Role"?  Or maybe just "extraneous", but that seems entirely too dismissive.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a little informal, but "going above and beyond" can convey the meaning of someone who takes initiative.

Comment: Extraneous is usually off topic. Main topics, extraneous topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest **supra-professional** activities or achievements.

[supra](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/supra)

> a prefix meaning “above, over” ( supraorbital ) or “beyond the limits
>   of, outside of” ( supramolecular; suprasegmental ).

For instance [in this article](https://case.edu/affil/sce/Texts_2006/Seidel.htm?nw_view=1481338021)

> Dana attributed to the journalist a supra-professional status by
>   calling on him to be “universal.”

Or [here](https://pjp-eu.coe.int/documents/1017981/3084952/2005_trading_up_NFL_coepub.pdf/197bc0f3-f939-44f8-b31b-5698b83566ec)

> In the wake of this process, supra-professional qualifications –
>   key-qualifications or lifelong learning – and social skills are
>   gaining increasingly in importance.

A less elevated choice might be **supplementary** activities/achievements.
[Supplement](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/supplement)

> something added to complete a thing, supply a deficiency, or reinforce
>   or extend a whole.